# If $P$ is a poset such that $\forall Q \subset P$ has infimum, then $P$ is a complete lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

If $P$ is a poset such that $\forall Q \subset P$ has infimum, then $P$ is a complete lattice

My try

Let $Q \subset P$ and let be $Q' \subset P$ the set of all uppers bounds of $Q$

then $Q'$ has infimum $\wedge Q'$ then $\forall q \in Q$ $q\leq \wedge Q'$

and for all $q' \in Q'$ $q\leq q'$ and $\wedge Q' \leq q'$

then $\wedge Q' $ is the supremum of $Q$ and then $P$ is a complete lattice

Comment: It's not hard, but I would expect more details on why the infimum of $Q'$ is an upper bound of $Q$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring  because i defined $Q'$ as the set of all upper bounds of $Q$ or my statement can be not true? the infimum of all upper bound can not be an upper bound of $Q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement
$$
\forall q \in Q, q \leq \bigwedge Q’ \tag1
$$
in your second line is true, but you need to explain a little bit more.

Can you see why
$$
\forall q \in Q \, \forall q’ \in Q’, q \leq q’
$$
is true? Can you see why this implies $(1)$?

Also, note that $(1)$ means $\bigwedge Q’$ is an element of $Q’$, so, $\bigwedge Q’$ is the *least element of* $Q’$. In other words, $\bigwedge Q’$ is the least upper bound (a.k.a. supremum) of $Q$.

Comment: yeah its because if $\wedge Q' $ is not in $Q'$ then exist $x \in Q$ such that $\wedge Q' \leq x $ and that contradicts with the fact that $\wedge Q'$ is the infimum right?

Comment: Don't try too hard, $(1)$ says that $\bigwedge Q’$ is greater than or equal to every element of $Q$, which is the meaning of being an upper bound of $Q$.

Comment: @GustavoOrtega I noticed that you didn't accept this answer nor in fact any answer on any of your questions. Perhaps you didn't realize how this is supposed to work yet. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers); it might also be a good idea to take the [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site (link at the bottom of the page).